# Angularjs filters on different object properties within array

Tags: angularjs, filter

```
 "Empl": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jhon",
        "phone": "9999999999",
        "address": {
            "city": "Pune",
            "address_line1": "ABC road",
            "address_line2": "XYZ building",
            "postal_code": "12455"
         }
     }

   Search: <input type="text" ng-model="query"></input>
   <tr ng-repeat="data in Empl | filter : {name:query,
   address:{city:query}}">
```

Filters not working in case we use same query string to filter two different properties of object inside array.

Answer (score 0):

You want to move your filter logic out of the template and into the controller as a function, then filter on the function.

If the query matches the item, or if the lowercase value of the name matches the lowercase value or the query, or if the lowercase value of the city matches the lowercase value of the query, the function returns true, otherwise it returns false.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in Empl | filter : search">


$scope.search = function(item) {
    if (!$scope.query || 
        (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query.toLowerCase()) != -1) || 
        (item.city.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query.toLowerCase()) != -1)             
       ){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```